# Verb for "Copying data and taking it away from an internal network"

Tags: single-word-requests

I work in a company where all non-public information is stored in a computer server on an internal network. A coworker of mine wants to force all employees who copy any record of the database and take it away from the office, whether physically (printed copies) or digitally (in a USB drive), to fill out an application form. The form includes several fields, such as time, user, name of data, and purpose. Data cannot leave the office unless this form is filled out, submitted and approved. Now the only question is, my coworker does not know what he should name this form.

I have considered the following:

> - **Data Removal Application Form**
>
> Ambiguous because removal may also sound like deleting a data file.
>
> - **Data Extraction Application Form**
>
> To extract a data, you apply an algorithm on that data, which isn't
>   the case here.
>
> - **Data Takeout Application Form**
>
> Ambiguous because takeout sounds like cut-and-pasting, not copying.
>   "Data takeout" is also a part of the GDPR, used specifically to
>   describe the action of exporting personal information from a service
>   for future migration.
>
> - **External Data Usage Application Form**
>
> Sounds like using external data
>
> - **External Usage of Internal Data Application Form**
>
> Too damn complicated.

Can someone suggest a more precise and shorter (if possible) name for this form?

Comment: Call it *Data Request* and be done with it.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Given the subjective nature of this, i would suggest shooting that is either simple to say, or has a decent acronym. I would avoid the "Data Extraction Application Form" as you'll get jokes about management of data being DEAF

Comment: You might want to rephrase your request. It seems to me that you look for an exception for internal non_disclosure rules. So maybe Confidentiality Exemption Application Form would suit your request better.